# Definite integral property

Tags: definite-integrals

I need to prove or disprove this fact

If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then there exists a number $c$ in the open interval $(a,b)$ such that

$$\int_a^c f(x) \, dx = \int_c^b f(x) \,dx$$

I have tried to use this property

$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^c f(x) \,dx +   \int_c^b f(x) \,dx $$

but I am not able to prove it or find a counterexample

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $c \in [a,b]$, let
$$
g(c) = \int_a^c f(x)dx - \int_c^b f(x) dx.
$$
The function $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Moreover $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ are of opposite signs. The conclusion follows from the Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Great solution, thanks

Comment: @Usser123456798: You're welcome. Since you're new to this website, let me tell you it is customary to upvote and/or accept useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Think about the function $F(t) = \int_a^t f(x)dx$.  It is continuous.  Now apply the intermediate value theorem with the constant $\frac12\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, can you explain a little bit more please.

Comment: I'm not sure how to involve $ \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx $ in the intermediate value theorem

Comment: It is the constant, which is between $F(a)$ and $F(b)$.